# I'm making an image slider but only the first image displays it does not display the rest

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an image slider with images that hava name ending with the numbers 1 to 5 but only the first image displays. the path is fine and i've tried displaying each picture separately and that worked ...

```
<head>

<title>jQuery Image Slider</title>

<script src = "jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<style>

    #container {
        height: 300px;
        width: 1350px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    #img {
        height: 300px;
        width: 1350px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #left-holder {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 100px;
    }

    #right-holder {
        height: 100px;
        width: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        top: 100px;
    }

    .left {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .right {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 0px;
    }

</style>

<script>

    var imageCount = 1;
    var totalImages = 5;

    function slide(x) {
        var Image = document.getElementById("img");
        imageCount = imageCount + x;
        if (imageCount > totalImages)
            imageCount = 1;
        if (imageCount < 1)
            imageCount = totalImages;
        Image.src = "E:\JavaScript work\Web Project\carousel"+imageCount+".jpg";
    }

    window.setInterval(function slideAuto() {
        var Image = document.getElementById("img");
        imageCount = imageCount + 1;
        if (imageCount > totalImages)
            imageCount = 1;
        if (imageCount < 1)
            imageCount = totalImages;
        Image.src = "E:\JavaScript work\Web Project\carousel"+imageCount+".jpg";
    }, 1000);

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id = "container">

        <img id = "img" src = "E:\JavaScript work\Web Project\carousel1.jpg" />

        <div id = "left-holder">
            <img class = "left" onClick = "slide(-1)" src = "E:\JavaScript work\Web Project\left.png" />
        </div>

        <div id = "right-holder">
            <img class = "right" onClick = "slide(1)" src = "E:\JavaScript work\Web Project\right.png" />
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** You are using backslash `\` in `src`. Javascript uses backslash to escape.

`Image.src = "E:\JavaScript work\Web Project\carousel"+imageCount+".jpg";`

**Solution:** Either use forward slash `/` or if you still want to use  backslash you can use `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Instead this

```
Image.src = "E:\JavaScript work\Web Project\carousel"+imageCount+".jpg";
```

use this:

```
Image.src = "E:\\JavaScript work\\Web Project\\carousel"+imageCount+".jpg";
```

at all better use relative address in image src.